# Matching values NOT in domain values of DQS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, data-quality, data-quality-services

I am using SQL Server 2012 Data Quality Services. I would like to consider any value that does not exist under domain values as Invalid. For example, if I have the values of 'abc', 'def' listed as correct in my domain values tab under domain management within a knowledge base but any value outside should be considered INVALID.

I have tried setting a domain rule that uses "Value is not in" then manually typed in the values 'abc', and 'def' but don't get an INVALID result when I cleanse data that has a domain value of 'xyz'.  Is there a better method within DQS that will allow me to consider any values outside of the values listed under domain values as INVALID?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The domain rules should be constructed such that any input-value that results in a "true" boolean outcome is considered a valid value in the domain.

So for your example, the domain rule should be "Value is in" instead of "Value is not in".